# Django target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, centos, mod-wsgi

**I am trying to deploy mod_wsgi with apache to run a django application but I am getting an error 500 internal server error The apache logs shows:**

```
[Fri May 05 22:38:22.709307 2017] [:error] [pid 2750] [remote 18.189.13.77:36] mod_wsgi (pid=2750): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/venv/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri May 05 22:38:22.709350 2017] [:error] [pid 2750] [remote 18.189.13.77:36] mod_wsgi (pid=2750): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/venv/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py'.
[Fri May 05 22:38:22.709379 2017] [:error] [pid 2750] [remote 18.189.13.77:36] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri May 05 22:38:22.709406 2017] [:error] [pid 2750] [remote 18.189.13.77:36]   File "/var/www/html/venv/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Fri May 05 22:38:22.709441 2017] [:error] [pid 2750] [remote 18.189.13.77:36]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Fri May 05 22:38:22.709465 2017] [:error] [pid 2750] [remote 18.189.13.77:36] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

**Server information:**

- Server: CentOS 7
- Django: 2.0
- Python: 3.6
- Apache: 2.4.6
- Installed: mod_wsgi

I followed steps from URL(https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=httpd&f=20) but only failed until the last step.

**My django in virtual env /var/www/html/venv/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py:**

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testproject.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**My Apache /etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf:**

```
WSGIDaemonProcess testapp python-path=/var/www/html/venv/testproject:/var/www/html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup testapp
WSGIScriptAlias /django /var/www/html/venv/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py
<Directory /var/www/html/venv/testproject>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I followed http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use to check system environment.
/var/www/html/test_wsgi.py

```
import sys
def application(environ,start_response):
    status = '200 OK'

    output = ''
    output += 'sys.version = %s\n' % repr(sys.version)
    output += 'sys.prefix = %s\n' % repr(sys.prefix)
    output += 'sys.path = %s\n' % repr(sys.path)
    output += 'mod_wsgi.process_group = %s\n' % repr(environ['mod_wsgi.process_group'])
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]
```

**UI shows:**

```
sys.version = '2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07) \n[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]'
sys.prefix = '/usr'
sys.path = ['/var/www/html/venv/testproject', '/var/www/html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
mod_wsgi.process_group = 'testapp'
```

Authority: django.conf(777), Firewall port enabled 80, 443 and 8000

Can anyone suggest me how to fix it? like set any configurations on httpd/conf? or setting any python to sys.path? Please try to describe in details because I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Your mod_wsgi is likely compiled for a different Python version, or you haven't correctly set up your Python virtual environment if Django was installed into one.

Comment: When I ran command: "python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000", it's looks normally on web. Can this step means python version and virtual environment works good?? or other things I need to check?

Comment: You are explicitly saying what Python to run. The mod_wsgi module could be compiled against different version. Review http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use and http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html and ensure your directories/files are readable by the user Apache runs your code as.

Comment: Thank you so much. I found out that I need to create a new virtual environment with "Python 3.6"'s command and problem solved!!

Comment: Confused. That ``sys.version`` says mod_wsgi was compiled for 2.7. The virtual environment would have to use 2.7, not 3.6.

Comment: Yes, it looks weird but it's worked. And I don't know why.

Comment: Be prepared for it to erupt in flames and kill you if you try and use any Python package with a C extension component. You can't mix C extensions across versions.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness reminding. I will try to reinstall server and all packages again.

Comment: I reinstalled again, but server shows the same situation. If I use Python3.6's new feature in function, it will show error because Python2.7. If I run by command "python3.6 runserver 0.0.0.0:8000", then its work. So I think my problem now is on how to change default python. Thanks again, and I think I should delete this post?

Comment: So you need to see if CentOS has mod_wsgi which is compiled for Python 3.6, otherwise need to compile mod_wsgi yourself. This isn't about changing the default Python version. And don't delete the question.

Comment: Got it. I will try this way out.